# Wireshark find DNS response "Refused"

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, wireshark

I'm looking for a way to filter a packet capture in wireshark for instances where our server responds with "Refused" to a recursive DNS query.

`dns.resp.type==` doesn't seem to offer anything that I see as a match to my request, do I need to look somewhere other than under `dns.resp` altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/d/dns.html you need to use `dns.flags.rcode` defined as:

> dns.flags.rcode   Reply code  Unsigned integer, 2 bytes   1.0.0 to 3.4.9

"Reply code" is defined in §4.1.1. of RFC 1035 as "response code"
with "Refused" being value 5:

> 5               Refused - The name server refuses to
> perform the specified operation for
> policy reasons.  For example, a name
> server may not wish to provide the
> information to the particular requester,
> or a name server may not wish to perform
> a particular operation (e.g., zone
> transfer) for particular data.

As Wireshark defines it as 2 bytes, maybe it is the whole structure depicted in the RFC:

```
                                    1  1  1  1  1  1
      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                      ID                       |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

So to compare `RCODE` to value 5 you may have to mask other bits.

Comment: Thank you; `dns.flags.rcode==5 and ip.dst==u.v.w.x` gives me exactly what I'm after.